# Mirroring ubuntu/debian release CD images?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, mirroring

I'd like to create a mirror for Ubuntu and Debian. I have apt-mirror installed, but I'm not sure what to place in my /etc/apt/mirror.list to mirror just the CD images. Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: apt-mirror is for mirroring the package repositories, not the CD images.  You might want to update your question asking about a tool to mirror the CD images.

Comment: BTW, why would you want to mirror the CD images instead of the repositories?  Assuming you have a working network adapter, the mini.iso is all I ever need/want.

Answer (score 2):

Debian disk images are well.. debian disk images. Debian has a howto on how to set up [your own mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror) - which is by duplicating a current mirror via rsync or other means

apt-mirror does repositories, and quite honestly, as zoredache said, those repos and a minimal installer disk should be good for most things.

Answer (score 1):

`jigdo` is the somewhat preferred method for creating CD images for Debian.  You can read more about it [here](http://debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/).  It beats downloading the entire image every time there's a change since it can "upgrade" an existing image.